# Changing all occurences of similar word in csv python

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I want to replace one specific word, 'my' with 'your'.  But seems my code can only change one appearance.

```
import csv
path1 = "/home/bankdata/levelout.csv"
path2 = "/home/bankdata/leveloutmodify.csv"
in_file = open(path1,"rb")
reader = csv.reader(in_file)
out_file = open(path2,"wb")
writer = csv.writer(out_file)

with open(path1, 'r') as csv_file:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    col_count = 0
    for row in csvreader:
        while row[col_count] == 'my':
            print 'my is used'
            row[col_count] = 'your'
            #writer.writerow(row[col_count])               
        writer.writerow(row)               
        col_count +=1
```

let's say the sentences is

```
'my book is gone and my bag is missing'
```

the output is

```
your book is gone and my bag is missing
```

the second thing is I want to make it appear without comma separated:

```
print row
```

the output is

```
your,book,is,gone,and,my,bag,is,missing,
```

Comment: `help(str.replace)` will probably help you a lot but your code isn't working because you increment `col_count` every row so it really isn't really counting columns.

Comment: you could also use the `delimeter` argument on the `csv.writer` constructor as seen [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to use a space for separation instead of commas.

Comment: thanks. i have solved the problem for replacing every occurrence of the word 'my' with 'your'.

Answer (score 0):

for the second problem, im still trying to find the correct one as it keeps giving me the same output with comma separated.

```
with open(path1) as infile, open(path2, "w") as outfile:
    for row in infile:
        outfile.write(row.replace(",", ""))
print row
```

it gives me the result:

```
your,book,is,gone,and,my,bag,is,missing
```

I send out this sentence to my Nao robot and the robot seems pronouncing awkwardly as there are commas in between each word.

I solved it by:

```
with open(path1) as infile, open(path2, "w") as outfile:
    for row in infile:
       outfile.write(row.replace(",", ""))
with open(path2) as out:
    for row in out:
       print row
```

It gives me what I want:

```
your book is gone and your bag is missing too
```

However, any better way to do it?

Comment: I think you're trying to do simple thing the hardest way. Try simplify you're file parser to accept space in sentence. And use other separator in your file...